# Como passar dados de um php a outro, sem form?

Tags: php

Um pergunta bem simples, porém, não sei ou não lembro.
Como posso enviar dados de um arquivo php para outro, tb em php? Não é o caso de form.

Arquivo php 1:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Prototype-Version,X Requested-With');

include_once("conPDO.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$msg = utf8_decode($_GET['mensagem']);
$idUsuario  = $_GET['idUsuario'];
$idCep  = $_GET['idCep'];
$nomeRemetente  = $_GET['nome'];
$usuarioRemetente  = $_GET['usuario'];
$uf = $_GET['uf'];
$cidade = $_GET['cidade'];
$bairro = $_GET['bairro'];
$logradouro = $_GET['logradouro'];
$dia  = $_GET['dia'];
$hora  = $_GET['hora'];
$foto = '';

$cidade = utf8_decode($cidade);
$bairro = utf8_decode($bairro);
$logradouro = utf8_decode($logradouro);

header('Location: websocket/src/MyApp/Chat.php?msg='.$msg);
```

**Quero passar essas variáveis, acima, para o seguinte php abaixo**

Arquivo php 2:

```
<?php
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
echo $msg;

namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');
        $dados = json_decode($msg, true);
        $dados['id'] = $from->resourceId;


        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {

                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send(json_encode($dados));

        }
    }
```

Comment: aponte  o local especifico, no segundo arquivo, onde as variáveis seriam lidas..  há formas diversas de resolver desde um grosseiro uso de  `global` à orientação a objetos..

Comment: Desculpe, mas como assim, apontar o local específico no segundo arquivo? E não seria no primeiro?

Comment: mostre onde quer que as variaveis do primeiro arquivo sejam lidas no segundo arquivo...  faz um desenho, coloca um  comentario no codigo, enfim

Comment: @DanielOmine, não tenho como desenhar aqui kkk mas coloquei em negrito, dê uma relida.

Comment: desculpe.. inviável responder...  precisa colaborar se quer alguma ajuda né, pois toma tempo alheio...

Comment: Amigo, já coloquei em negrito o que preciso, isso não ajuda?

Comment: Você tem uma página PHP que recebe os dados e quer passa-los para outra página em PHP? Porque não tratar os dados na própria página que os recebe?

Comment: Por que esse outra página é uma API que está pronta e que peguei do git, entende @FleuquerLima?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tente isso no **arquivo2.php**:

```
include 'Arquivo1.php';

public function Alguma_Função() {
    global $msg;
}
```

ou

```
include 'Arquivo1.php';
private $newmsg = '';

public function setMSG() {
    global $msg;
    $this->newmsg = $msg;
}
```

Comment: Resolveu o problema do autor da pergunta, mas acho importante deixar claro pra todos os leitores que neste caso não tem "variaveis sendo passadas de um PHP pra outro" como pedido na pergunta, e sim o arquivo2 está sendo executado com uma cópia interna do código do 1. NOTA: só estou esclarecendo para não induzir outros leitores a erro. Nem é culpa da resposta, mas como o autor da pergunta não tem o conhecimento básico de PHP para códigos da complexidade postada na pergunta e aceitou a resposta que soluciona de outra maneira, alguém poderia achar que a resposta de fato passa parâmetros.

Comment: @Bacco vai da interpretação do que significa "passar de um arquivo para o outro", de fato; acho eu, que essa não é a melhor maneira.

Comment: Novamente, nao é uma crítica à resposta (afinal, gerou o "efeito final" que o autor queria). Apenas um alerta pra quem tá aprendendo e amanha ou depois ler a pergunta e resposta, entender que é uma solução que resolve (bem resolvido) mas por uma razão técnica diferente do descrito na pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Está bem difícil de entender sua pergunta. Mas algumas alternativas:

Redirecionar do **arquivo1** para o **arquivo2** passando os dados via GET (grosseiramente):

Sua URL ficaria http://seudominio.com.br?variavel1=XXX&variavel2=YYY&variavel3=ZZZ

E no **arquivo2** você recupera usando o **$_GET**: Por exemplo:

```
$variavel1 = $_GET['variavel1'];
```

Outra forma é você armazenar isso em uma variável global, incluir o **arquivo1** no **arquivo2** e recuperar ela.

**Utilizando sessions**

No **arquivo1**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['msg'] = $_GET['msg'];
header('Location: arquivo2.php');
```

No **arquivo2**

```
session_start();
$msg = $_SESSION['msg'];
```

Comment: Sério que minha pergunta está tão complicada de entender? Acho que está tão óbvia que você não estão entendendo kkkk.
Eu quero que as varáveis:
$msg, $idUsuario, $idCep, $nomeRemetente, $usuarioRemetente, $uf, $cidade, $bairro, $logradouro, $dia, $hora, $foto, sejam transferidas, enviadas, automaticamente, de um arquivo php para outro arquivo php.

Comment: Para usar com GET, eu teria que passar via url, e um usuário teria que clicar em um botão para isso e não quero. Deveria ser algo como um header('Location:....');

Comment: Sim, a URL você pode acessar como quiser... seja com a ação de um botão ou com um header('Location'). Se pretende automatizar, utiliza o header passando os valores via get

Comment: Sim, eu tentei fazer isso: header('Location: websocket/src/MyApp/Chat.php?msg='.$msg); mas não deu certo. E isso: $msg = $_GET['msg'];
echo $msg;
no outro arquivo.

Comment: Editei o post para você ver como estão os arquivos, agora.

Comment: Coloquei uma alternativa na resposta com a utilização de sessão. Acho que vai resolver seu problema. No arquivo2, após utilizar a session você pode destruí-la

Comment: da uma include no arquivo 2 com o arquivo 1 e use o `global $msg`

Comment: Assim fechou:
include_once('websocket/src/MyApp/Chat.php');
global $msg;